# Python, VIM: How do i count the lines in a VIM register?

Tags: python, vim

The Python, VIM bindings give me ways of manipulating: *windows, buffers and ranges* but absolutely no way of messing with registers.

```
vim.command('let @".="%s"' % vim.current.buffer[start - 1])
```

I can append lines to the default cut&paste register, but is there a way to count the lines in it, so i can paste. I need to make space before pasting or the lines get merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you can get the value of a vim register by `vim.eval("@a")` for example.

If you want to count the lines (`\n`) in a register you can do it either in vim or python.

E.g. in vim:

```
len(split(@a, '\n'))
```

in python

```
#var is the variable containing @a in vim
len(re.split("\n",var))
```